# replace variables of a file with reference to values in another file

Tags: python, unix, awk, grep

I have two files

```
file1.txt
variable1=string1 with spaces characters
variable2=string2 with spaces characters
variable3=string3 with spaces characters

file2.txt
sometext1 textvariable1 sometext2 sometext3
variable2 sometext4 sometextcharactersvariable1 charactersvariable3 sometext5 variable2
....................
```

I would like the file2.txt with all the variables replaced with the values in file1.txt

i tried multiple grep and awk commands,python codes to read each word , compare and replace read file options

```
fgrep -w -o -f "file1.txt" "file2.txt"
awk '/PATTERN/{system("cat file1");next}1' file2
```

but this works for only one variable.
I know i have to loop through each word in file2 and compare it with file1 and then replace. But not sure how to.

expected output:

```
sometext1 string1 sometext2 sometext3
string2 sometext4 string1 string3 sometext5 string2
................
```

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do what you want, using Python. This was tested with both Python2 and Python3.

```
import sys
import re

with open('file1.txt') as fp:
    subs = dict(l.strip().split('=', 1) for l in fp)

with open('file2.txt') as fp:
    text = fp.read()

text = re.sub('|'.join(subs), lambda m: subs[m.group(0)], text)

sys.stdout.write(text)
```

Notes:

- Note the use of `fp.read()` to read in the entire text file. If this consumes too much memory, you can do `for line in fp:` instead.
- Note the use of a dict comprehension and generator expression to create the `subs` dictionary. Essentially, it splits each line into `variable` and `string` components and creates the dictionary.
- Note the use of `'|'.join()` to create the regular expression. You end up with `'string1|string2|string3'`. If `file1.txt` is uncontrolled input, then you might have a problem: what if the user enters `.*=bar` in the input file?
- Note the use of a callable as the 2nd parameter to `re.sub()`. This allows arbitrary code to be run. In particular, it allows a lookup in the `subs` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next }
     { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i in a) $i=a[$i] }1' FS='=' file1.txt FS=' ' file2.txt
```

The output:

```
sometext1 string1 sometext2 sometext3
string2 sometext4 string1 string3 sometext5 string2
```

Comment: Thank you somuch for your reply. What if the file2.txt is not delimited with " ". in some scenarios i have "variable1text ?variable2text" can you help me

Comment: @venkatsai, this `?variable2text` can't be considered as a proper variable name in your case. If you have some additional cases with additional logic - you should update your question and description

Comment: @venkatsai, ok, but my solution covers your initial condition which differs much from your current one

Answer (score 0):

If the first file is small enough to comfortably into memory, you could read the first file into a dictionary and use the fileimport module: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fileinput.html?highlight=fileinput#fileinput

The following was tested in Python3

```
import fileinput
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
    my_map = {}
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split('=')
        my_map[key] = value

for line in fileinput.input('file2.txt', inplace=True):
    new_line = line
    for key, value in my_map.items():
        new_line = new_line.replace(key, value)
    print(new_line,)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get a value error key, value = line.strip().split('=')
ValueError: too many values to unpack, I think the values in the value are many. any help on this ?

Comment: .strip() is removing whitespace. .split('=') should break each line up into before the '=' and after it. Is there more than one '=' on some of your lines in file1?

Comment: I dont have more than one =. but i have other special characters like $ ( ) |

Comment: That's odd. Is there a new line character between each set of 'variable1=string1'?

Comment: yes. there is . all the variables start in a new line and sometimes the variable is so lengthy that it goes into next line

Comment: if you run this, do you see anything that isn't a 1?
    with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line.count('='))

Comment: That means that for each 'line' in that file (as far as python sees) some have more than one '=' in them. In that case, what do you want your code to do? Should any later '=' signs be considered part of string1, string2 etc.?

Comment: Hi need everything after the first = to be appended to the key.I am trying to modify it this way.my_map = {}
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split('=',1)
        my_map[key].append(value)

Comment: I modified into this.key, value = line.strip().split('=',1)
        my_map[key]=value it works for all those that have a single = i am trying for a way to append the content to key incase of more than one = @saoili

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163437/discussion-between-saoili-and-venkatsai).